# Driver for AMD Graphic card

Tags: amd-graphics, amdgpu

Here is my graphic card series...

```
me@linux:~$ lspci | grep Display
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230]
```

Anybody please provide instructions on how to install Linux driver for Ubuntu 16.04 or later.. Thanks.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD . What is wrong with the open source driver ?

Comment: Did you tried this page as well? https://askubuntu.com/questions/580788/what-the-best-way-to-install-the-graphics-drivers-for-a-radeon-hd-8550m-on-a-int

Comment: I don't have any problem installing open source driver. Does `radeon` supports my graphic card? `man radeon` doesn't display `R5 M230` in supported list.

Comment: It is supported by one of the open source drivers. It doiesn't matter which one.

Comment: `sudo apt dist-upgrade` installed the driver `radeon`. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open-source driver for AMD Radeon graphics adapters is already installed together with Ubuntu. You don't need to do anything.